# How to create a dynamic javascript statement in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, dynamic

I want to set the value in a series of reactive vars like these below more efficiently:

```
Template.instance().editType.set(false);
Template.instance().editZip.set(!template.editZip.get());
Template.instance().editHeadCount.set(false);
Template.instance().editDate.set(false);
Template.instance().editTime.set(false) ;
Template.instance().editDuration.set(false);
```

I have wrote the following function, but it doesn't work as I am getting an error (TypeError: Template.instance(...).eval is not a function):

```
function turnOffSelect(currentDiv) {
    var divArray = ['.editType', '.editZip', '.editHeadCount', '.editDate', '.editTime', '.editDuration' ]  
    for (i = 0; i < divArray.length; i++) {
        if (divArray[i] != currentDiv) {
            Template.instance().eval(divArray[i]).set(false);           
        }
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: `eval` hasn't been a property of objects for a while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just index using bracket notation instead of resorting to eval?

```
function turnOffSelect(currentDiv) {
  ['editType', 'editZip', 'editHeadCount', 'editDate', 'editTime', 'editDuration'].forEach(
    el => { Template.instance()[el].set(false) }
  );
}
```